# Does Ubuntu really not support Google 2-factor authentication?

Tags: email, evolution, gmail, two-factor-authentication

I have spent the best part of a day trying to get Ubuntu 17.04 to work happily with Google 2-factor authentication. I found that with 2FA turned on in my Google account settings I could add the account to the Online Accounts system settings. All looked ready to go. But on opening Evolution I found that although the mail came in and the contacts synced, the calendar refused to appear.

There followed a few hours trying to get it to work with the Gnome Calendar app, Nylas email, removing and resetting settings, uninstalling and reinstalling Evolution. No joy.

So I remove 2FA from Google account settings, and bingo, all my calendar data floods into Evolution and the Calendar app.

Wonderful, but I really did not want to remove 2FA from the lynch-pin of my digital life. Is there a solution?

Glutton for punishment... once I have set up my Google account on Ubuntu I am going to try my iCloud account.

Answer (score 4):

Many things don't support 2FA. The usual solution is to use [app passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en):

> An App password is a 16-digit passcode that gives an app or device
>   permission to access your Google Account. If you use
>   2-Step-Verification and are seeing a “password incorrect” error when
>   trying to access your Google Account, an App password may solve the
>   problem. Most of the time, you’ll only have to enter an App password
>   once per app or device, so don’t worry about memorizing it.
>   [...]
>
> #### How to generate an App password
>
> 1. Visit your [App passwords](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords) page. You may be asked to sign in to your Google Account.
> 2. At the bottom, click **Select app** and choose the app you’re using.
> 3. Click **Select device** and choose the device you’re using.
> 4. Select **Generate**.
> 5. Follow the instructions to enter the App password (the 16 character code in the yellow bar) on your device.
> 6. Select **Done**.
>
> Once you are finished, you won’t see that App password code again.
>   However, you will see a list of apps and devices you’ve created App
>   passwords for.

Comment: Thank you muru, that looks like the way to go. So I will re-enable 2FA and have another go.